# Can't run git commands using SSH agent forwarding

Tags: git, ssh

I want to run a git command on my VPS server, as in the following:

```
ssh -A user@mydomain.com 'git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:myuser/repo.git'
```

but I get the error message:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can run other commands using SSH agent forwarding. (On other servers, this commands works fine.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Host key verification failed" message likely means that the SSH client on your VPS doesn't trust the git server.

Try this instead:

```
ssh -A user@mydomain.com 'ssh -T -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no git@bitbucket.org < /dev/null'
ssh -A user@mydomain.com 'git ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:myuser/repo.git'
```

The first command should cause the SSH key to be cached in your `.ssh/known_hosts` on the VPS. From then on, the second command should work.

You could probably also solve this by creating a `.ssh/config` on the VPS user account, containing something like this (untested):

```
Host bitbucket.org
    User git
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Assuming the above configuraiton snippet works, it would save you one SSH connection.